# Excel formula to return highest score (from one column) for each category (another coulmn) in a table

Tags: excel, rank, highest

Basically I envisage having a table of risks in Excel for various projects. Each risk has a score and its project name on one row of the table (amongst various other pieces of information).

What I would like is a formula, repeated in 3 cells with minor adjustments, to return the 1st, 2nd and 3rd highest scored risks for a given project. The project would ideally be selected by a reference in the formula to another cell with a dropdown list of all the projects so you could select the project in the drop down and see the corresponding highest risks.

I have tried using =Large([table array],[1/2/3]), =vlookup and =offset - but this just returns the highest three scores in the whole table - I can't figure out how to make the formula look at only the set of rows pertaining to a given project.

Many thanks for any help or advice offered!

Comment: Hi @EBAK87, maybe the best place to ask this question is on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel

Comment: Please include some sample data and expected results. It sounds like you want something like LARGE IF entered as an array formula.

Comment: I'm not sure how to attach sample data.. but it would essentially be: column headings: Project (many projects, each with many risks); Risk description (unique); Risk Impact (number from 1-5); Risk Liklihood (number 1-5); Overall Risks score (=Impact*Likelihood); Risk owner + dates (irrelevant for this exercise).............. then I want the output to be on another sheet, that sheet would have a drop down box to select the Project then the formula in question would look at that selected project, and pull the 3 highest scored risks for that project from the whole list of risks. (obvs in 3 cells)